# Generator supply not working with Automatic Changeover

Tags: electrical

I am using [Havells Changeover](http://goo.gl/e6nwKp). There are three input,

- Main
- Gen
- Load

Main has two Neutral wire, Gen has one, but Load has no Neutral wire

when system is on Main power, it works fine. but when Generator is started i don't get electricity in house.

lights blinks a little whole time.

is it due to missing neutral wire in Load?

should i remove one wire from Main and put in the Load? all are neutral wires same, or there is some difference

Comment: Where are you located? Codes are different in different countries.

Answer (score 3):

Neutrals are not the same!   The factory certainly would not have wasted money on separate neutral terminals if they were not necessary.

It needs to be hooked up according to the instructions for that unit.  In my country that is the **law**.  Why? Because the unit is only safety tested/certified for correct configuration. A wrong configuration could be dangerous.

It sounds like whoever hooked it up did not follow basic instructions.  Don't let them do any more work on your house!

Comment: you are right, as i mentioned above. Main has two neutral wires inserted into it, Load has no Neutral. but its functions on Main supply. But when Gen is on. it does not work(no power in home). as Load is not getting Neutral now, that is the problem. Today i have kept one neutral cable in Main whose other part is in ELCB and have put second Neutral in Load. so now Main is working fine. i will check for generator tomorrow.